# Use kramdown with pygments in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, pygments, kramdown

I want to use [kramdown](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/) (with features such as fenced code blocks, inline attribute lists, header IDs) together with pygments for syntax highlighting (e.g. for LaTeX support, which is not available with CodeRay used by kramdown). Jekyll supports both kramdown and pygments, but apparently not the two together (unless I use Liquid tags which I would prefer not to).

I've also found some [plugin snippets](http://bloerg.net/2013/03/07/using-kramdown-instead-of-maruku.html) of how to make kramdown fenced code blocks spit pygments highlighted code, but unfortunately I don't know how to make that work.

I tried dumping all of the code from that site on some `_plugins/krampygs.rb` file, but then `jekyll build` complains about:

```
Generating... error: undefined method `matches'
```

If I supply some trivial `matches` and `output_ext` as instructed by [Jekyll plugin docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/), but then I don't know how to select this new converter for my `.md` files. Adding something like

```
markdown: MarkdownConverter
```

on my `_config.yml` only complains that this is not a valid option.

So, well, I restate my question: How can I use kramdown with pygments in Jekyll?

## Solution

With the help of Matthias (below), I was able to prepare this [Kramdown+Pygments plugin](https://github.com/navarroj/krampygs) for Jekyll 1.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author of "that site" here.

It depends on the Jekyll version. For the version when the post was written, that was enough. At least Jekyll 1.x requires that `matches` is defined in the `MarkdownConverter`, like so:

```
def matches(ext)
  ext =~ /^\.md$/i
end
```

Another problem that appears with Jekyll 1.x is that every custom Markdown converter is [ignored](http://bloerg.net/2013/05/06/moving-to-jekyll-1-0.html). I worked around this by by stating the output extension explicitly

```
def output_ext(ext)
  ".html"
end
```

and tell Jekyll that to look for a bogus Markdown extension by setting

```
markdown_ext: foo
```

in `_config.yml`.

Comment: Thanks! This finally solved the problem. I really wish kramdown+pygments were supported by Jekyll out of the box.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, this is the [plugin](https://github.com/navarroj/krampygs) I was finally able to make.

Comment: That's a really good idea to put this on GitHub! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the [plugin](https://github.com/navarroj/krampygs) created by [Juan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359178/juan-a-navarro), to be compatible with Jekyll 2.x, along with some other improvements.

It can be found here: https://github.com/mvdbos/kramdown-with-pygments.git